# \listoftodos is empty for the document with \todo

Tags: todonotes

The document contains several tex pages which are included with `\input`. The main.tex has `\usepackage{todonotes}` and a command to generate list of todos `\listoftodos`. The other page contains `\todo{some note}`. I see the todo note itself but the list of todos is empty.

Ideas?

Tried to have `\todo` and `\listoftodos` on the same page - the same result. `latex --version` is "pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)". Tried with two versions of todonotes.tex - "2012/07/25" and "2012/07/25". Thanks.

Comment: You should update your system. TeXLive 2009 is a little bit old ,,,

Comment: Would you please add a small sample of code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run pdfTeX on your file at least two times to see the list.